# LINQ To XML error: type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read an XML file, but getting `type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'` error as a result of the following query:

```
List<Data> dogs = (from q in doc.Descendants("dog")
    where (string)q.Attribute("name") == dogName
        select new Data
        {
            name = q.Attribute("name").Value,
            breed = q.Element("breed").Value,
            sex = q.Element("sex").Value
        }.ToList<Data>);
```

Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string breed { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public List<string> dogs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your closing parenthesis - you've got it at the end of the `ToList()` call, when you meant to put it at the end of the object initializer. Also, you're not actually calling the method - you're just specifying a method group. Finally, you can let type inference work out the type argument for you:

```
List<Data> dogs = (from q in doc.Descendants("dog")
                   where (string)q.Attribute("name") == dogName
                   select new Data
                   {
                       name = q.Attribute("name").Value,
                       breed = q.Element("breed").Value,
                       sex = q.Element("sex").Value
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure its not simple typo in question?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Well it would match the error in the title fairly reasonably, I think.

Comment: I missed it while looking for answer on the internet. You're right, will mark your post as answer. Thank you.